# Difference between `:/foo`, `qrc:/foo` and `qrc:///foo` paths in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, url, path, resources

This code succeeds:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
```

This code prints "failure":

```
QFile file("qrc:/main.qml");
if ( file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) ) {
    cout << "success" << endl;
} else {
    cout << "failure" << endl;
}
```

Changing the QFile constructor argument to `qrc:///main.qml` (as in the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#resource-collection-files-op-op-qrc)) doesn't fix it. Changing it to `:/main.qml` makes it print "success" though.

So I'm confused as to when to use each of the 3 forms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in your [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#resource-collection-files-op-op-qrc), `:/main.qml` is a file path, while `qrc:/main.qml` is an url.

The former can be used where a file path is required -- basically a `QString`, like with `QFile` constructor.

The latter can be used where an url is required, like with `QQmlApplicationEngine::load` through `QUrl`. It can not be used with `QFile` constructor where a path is needed.

About `qrc:///`, a simplified url syntax (without query, user/password, nor port) can be:

```
scheme:[//host][/]path
```

Which can lead to `scheme:/path` if you skip `host` part, or `scheme:///path` if you specify `host` as an empty string. From [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2):

> For example, **the "file" URI scheme is defined so that** no authority, **an empty host**, and "localhost" all **mean the end-user's machine**, whereas the "http" scheme considers a missing authority or empty host invalid.

Looks like Qt's developers followed the rules of the `file` scheme when designing their `qrc` scheme. After all, the resources here are just files "on the end-user's machine" (in fact, inside an executable on the end-user's machine). So `qrc:/main.qml` and `qrc:///main.qml` are just two writings of the same url.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) for complete url syntax.

Comment: Thanks, and what about `qrc:///`?

Comment: @StefanMonov: See your documentation link: "[...] the file path `:/images/cut.png` or the **URL** `qrc:///images/cut.png` [...]". Basically: `qrc:///` = URL.